# How do I embed the sqlite LIKE command in C?

Tags: c, sqlite, sql-like

I have the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM versions WHERE path LIKE '%/dir1%'
```

that works perfectly fine when executing from sqlite command prompt.

However, I am having trouble running this command from a C program.

It is a little bit tricky because in sqlite the %Q is used to pass in strings but LIKE also uses % to perform regular expression behavior.

Which sqlite function should I use from the API?

Comment: Just a shot in the dark: have you tried `%%` to represent one %?

Comment: That worked! Just used %% and it ran the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%%` is converted to `%`.

Making an answer to get accepted :)